# Sample multiple lists at once

Tags: r, list, sample

I have 10 lists. Every lists has 20 elements. I want to create a general list with elements from every 20 other lists. More specific, I am using the `sample` to take 2 elements from every list and then store them in my general list. For one sample I do:

```
general_list=sample(listx,2,replace=TRUE)
```

My question is: Is there a way to do that at once? Something like:

```
general_list=sample(listx,listy,listk,...,2,replace=TRUE)
```

I am new on this so this might be very simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
a <- as.list(1:5)
b <- as.list(6:10)
c <- as.list(11:15)

dat <- list(a,b,c)
res <- unlist(lapply(dat, sample, 2), recursive = FALSE)
```

`res` is a list of 2 elements from each `a`,`b` and `c`. They are ordered in the sense that res[1:2] come from `a`, res[3:4] from `b` and so on. If you want to sample this order as well use `sample(res)`